# formatting output in bash shell to remove special characters - linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, centos

I am issuing the command below against a logfile

```
grep "Oracle Audit" /var/adm/messages | awk '{print $6}'
```

How do I format the below output

```
Audit[9460]:
Audit[10507]:
Audit[10507]:
Audit[10507]:
```

to show only the numbers
e.g.

```
9460
10507
10507
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure `awk` solution, try

```
awk '{ sub("Audit\\[", "", $6); sub("]:", "", $6); print $6 }'
```

which replaces the undesired strings in `$6` with nothing. 
It is conceivable that Cyrus's answer might be faster than this one.  Or not.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `awk`, `grep` can do that alone:

```
grep -oP 'Oracle Audit\[\K[0-9]+(?=\])' /var/adm/messages
```

The `\K` after `Oracle Audit\[` resets the beginning of the reported match to this point. So it's not part of the match. After the numbers you want to print there is a look ahead `(?=)`. Similar to the `\K` sequence.

It will print:

```
9460
10507
10507
10507
```